# Constante visível em toda a aplicação

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Olá, eu estou desenvolvendo o *frontend* para uma `API` que desenvolvi e estou com um pequeno problema, a `URL` da minha `API` estou definindo em todos os módulos que utilizo, gostaria de criar uma constante global para a aplicação para setar o `URL` da API e utilizar em todos os módulos.

Alguém sabe me dizer se isso é possível, e caso seja, poderiam me mostrar algum exemplo disto?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existem alguns métodos, como o uso de `$rootScope` (que é o mais comum e também o pior) que cria uma variável global.

Mas você também pode (aliás, DEVE) usar uma `constant` para este fim, desde que tenha certeza que a variável nunca irá mudar, o que é o seu caso.

Neste arquivo você pode definir não só uma, como várias variáveis a serem acessadas posteriormente. Veja o exemplo:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.constant('minhaConstant', {
    url: 'meu/caminho/arquivo.php',
    error: 'Algo deu errado, tente novamente',
    title: 'Meu Título'
});
```

E quando precisar usar, você deve fazer a injeção da constant, como qualquer outro caso, veja:

```
app.controller('mainController', function(minhaConstant, $scope, $http){
    $scope.title = minhaConstant.title;

    $http.get(minhaConstant.url).then(function(response){
        console.log(response.data);
    });
})
```

No exemplo declarei outras variáveis, como título e mensagem de erro padrão, apenas para que você saiba que pode usar deste modo.