# Como eu uso uma key do web.config no controller?

Tags: angularjs, web.config

No meu web.config eu tenho a seguinte key:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="teste" value="teste"/>
<appSettings>
```

O que preciso fazer para utilizar essa key no meu controller?

Comment: Poderia ser mais específico sobre o que realmente quer fazer?  Você colocou como tag angularJs mas prentende utilizar de que forma? em que cenário?

Comment: @Felipe Tenho várias requisições ajax nos meus controllers, que chamam umas URL's que começa com o IP e o número da porta (que são fixos em todas as URL's). Porém esse começo fixo eu preciso colocar em uma variável, pra quando outra pessoa for utilizar meu projeto e tiver que alterar ip ou porta, altere apenas em um lugar. Um amigo meu sugeriu colocar no web.config, conforme mostrado acima, porém não sei como utilizar essa key no controller

Comment: Você se refere a controllers do AngularJs , ou do projeto que recebe as requisições, o web.config é o arquivo de configuração do seu projeto .net?

Comment: @Felipe Me refiro a controller do AngularJS. Sim

Comment: O web.config que você utilizou em sua tag é o arquivo de configuração de projetos .NET, se estamos falando apenas de AngularJS(front-end) você pode fazer 2 coisas:  Uma é criar uma constante JS que será utilizada por todo código javascript ,a outra é você fazer mais uma chamada ajax para um controller do projeto ASP.NET ou outra api que seja possível acessar, que tenha nos arquivos de configuração a chave que criar. Para ler do web.config no controller do ASP.NET você pode utilizar o comando WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["teste"] para pegar o valor da key definido no XML

Comment: É importante definimos o cenário que você possui, se você possui o projeto do front-end e também do back-end , podemos tratar a possibilidade de parametrizar isso no arquivo de configurações do projeto do back-end , se você só possui o projeto do AngularJs , o que podemos fazer é definirmos uma constante com o valor necessário.

Comment: @Felipe eu sou responsável pelo front, meu colega pelo back, ele cria os serviços e faço o consumo. Quando mostrei o que já foi feito para a área de T.I do cliente, eles sugeriram que eu colocasse o começo da URL que chamo no ajax numa variável, tudo pelo web.config do AngularJS, para que, se caso eles precisassem fazer alguma alteração, não precisaria entrar controller por controller, e sim apenas pelo arquivo web.config.

Comment: Eu sou novo na área, trabalho com desenvolvimento web não tem nem 1 ano, então não tenho muito conhecimento. Acredito que esse web.config que me refiro, seja o arquivo de configuração para que eu possa abrir o site pelo IIS

Comment: O angularJs, por padrão, não existe o arquivo web.config a não ser que você crie. Crie um módulo do angularJs contento todas as contantes que serão usadas por todo o código . Esse link contém o exemplo. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/134871/constante-vis%C3%ADvel-em-toda-a-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o